# Error when running SparkApp from docker container against Spark running in another container

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, docker, dependencies

I have a problem that's bothering me for a few days, and I'm pretty out of ideas.

I built a Spark docker container where Spark runs in standalone mode. Both master and worker are started there. This is machine running in Azure.

Now I tried to deploy my Spark Scala App in a separate container(same machine) where I pass the Spark master URL and other stuff I need to connect to Spark. Connection is seamless.

First problem I encountered was:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.1.0.4): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDDPartition
```

Then I made a folder of my dependencies except Spark, put them in a folder alongside my app JAR file and added them to SparkConf using `SparkConf.setJars`,

Now the strange thing happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.1.0.4): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

More than this, if I just run the scala app from my local machine using `java -cp <dependencies(including spark jars) cp> myApp.jar` it works perfectly, jobs run ok.

I don't have any `SPARK_HOME` locally and the `setJars` basically takes an empty list, as if I won't use it and it still works.
I guess it uses jars provided in the classpath when I run my app and I don't need to provide anything else.

If any of you guys have any ideas I would be grateful, I really can't explain myself why this doesn't work and I didn't do any Spark deployments until now. I mostly ran in embedded Spark.

Spark is same version in my app dependencies (2.0.0) as the one running in the docker container.
I used:
Scala 2.11.7 for my app
Java 1.8 on both containers(app, spark)

As requested here is the code of my app

```
  val jars = Option(new File(Properties.spark_jars_path).listFiles()).toList.flatten.map(_.getAbsolutePath)
  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster(RunUtils.determineMasterUrl(Properties.mode))
    .setAppName(RunUtils.SPARK_APP_NAME)
    .setJars(jars)
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", Properties.cassandra_connection_host)

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))

  case class Result(buyDate: Timestamp, endDate: Timestamp, maxDate: Timestamp, buyAmount: Double, buyRate: Double)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val DateFormatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

    val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> Properties.kafka_brokers, "auto.offset.reset" -> Properties.kafka_auto_reset_offset)

    //
    // BITSTAMP
    //
    val bitstampTopic = Set("bitstamp_trades")
    val bitstampStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, bitstampTopic)
    val bitstampTradeStream = bitstampStream.map(_._2).map { trade =>
      val jsonNode = JsonMapper.readTree(trade)
      Trade(
        "BITSTAMP",
        "BTC_USD",
        if(jsonNode.get("type").asInt() == 1) "SELL" else "BUY",
        DateFormatter.format(new Date(jsonNode.get("timestamp").asLong() * 1000)),
        new Date(jsonNode.get("timestamp").asLong() * 1000),
        jsonNode.get("amount").asDouble(),
        jsonNode.get("price").asDouble()
      )
    }

    bitstampTradeStream.saveToCassandra("coin_master", "trades", SomeColumns(
      "exchange_house",
      "exchange_currencies",
      "exchange_type",
      "date",
      "trade_time",
      "amount",
      "price")
    )
   ssc.start()
   ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide code where you are doing mapparttitons or code where you suppose why this error occurred?

Comment: Check the question again, I added the code.

Comment: ok, so just realised the problem is something inside my map function, when I'll solve, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was my map function.

More specifically this line was the problem:

```
val jsonNode = JsonMapper.readTree(trade)
```

JsonMapper is actually a configured ObjectMapper from Jackson library and to make it work I should have used `sparkContext.broadcast` because of some method that had to be called on each executor.

You can read more about why it didn't work here:
[Spark: broadcasting jackson ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495891/spark-broadcasting-jackson-objectmapper)

So, after changing my code to something like this it worked:

```
val broadcastValue = ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(JsonMapper)

val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> Properties.kafka_brokers, "auto.offset.reset" -> Properties.kafka_auto_reset_offset)

//
// BITSTAMP
//
val bitstampTopic = Set("bitstamp_trades")
val bitstampStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, bitstampTopic)
val bitstampTradeStream = bitstampStream.map(_._2).map { trade =>
  broadcastValue.value.registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule with RequiredPropertiesSchemaModule)
  val jsonNode = broadcastValue.value.readTree(trade)
  Trade(
    "BITSTAMP",
    "BTC_USD",
    if(jsonNode.get("type").asInt() == 1) "SELL" else "BUY",
    DateFormatter.format(new Date(jsonNode.get("timestamp").asLong() * 1000)),
    new Date(jsonNode.get("timestamp").asLong() * 1000),
    jsonNode.get("amount").asDouble(),
    jsonNode.get("price").asDouble()
  )
}
```