# Case Class serialization in Spark

Tags: serialization, apache-spark-sql, case-class

In a Spark app (Spark 2.1) I'm trying to send a case class as input parameter of a function that is meant to run on executors

```
object TestJob extends App {

  val appName = "TestJob"
  val out = "out"
  val p = Params("my-driver-string")

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName(appName)
    .getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

  (1 to 100).toDF.as[Int].flatMap(i => Dummy.process(i, p))
    .write
    .option("header", "true")
    .csv(out)
}

object Dummy {

  def process(i: Int, v:Params): Vector[String] = {
    Vector { if( i % 2 == 1) v + "_odd" else v + "_even" }
  }
}

case class Params(v: String)
```

When I run it with master local[*] everything goes well, while when running in a cluster, Params class state is not getting serialized and the output results in
**null**_even
**null**_odd
...

Could you please help me understanding what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling around I found this post that gave me the solution:[Spark broadcasted variable returns NullPointerException when run in Amazon EMR cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303827/spark-broadcasted-variable-returns-nullpointerexception-when-run-in-amazon-emr-c)

In the end the problem is due to the **extend Apps**